# What does the -mate suffix mean and where does it come from?

Tags: greek, affixes, morphemes

What does the suffix "-mate" mean? It makes a word into a verb, like with *automate* or *decimate*, but does it actually have a meaning? Is it perhaps Greek for "to make" or something?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @BillJ I searched for engines that would break apart the word and look at its morphological structure. I put *automate* into it, and it only told me about *auto*. I searched through a suffix dictionary and couldn't find *-mate*, but then I saw the dictionary didn't even talk about the suffixes meaning and origin anyways.

Comment: That's because these are not English morphemes. They were chunks of Latin morphology that were already attached when the words were borrowed from Latin.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is that true even of [automate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/automate), which is apparently a new back-formation of [automaton](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=automaton)? Because in such a case, the morphology would be borrowed even though "automate" itself is not.}

Answer (score 2):

The suffix you are looking for is actually ***[-ate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ate#etymonline_v_26660)***:

> ***word-forming element used in forming nouns from Latin words ending in -atus, -atum*** (such as estate, primate, senate). Those that came to English via Old and Middle French often arrived with -at, but an -e was added after c. 1400 to indicate the long vowel. ***The suffix also can mark adjectives formed from Latin past participles in -atus, -ata*** (such as desolate, moderate, separate); again, they often were adopted in Middle English as -at, with an -e appended after c. 1400.

decimate (v.)

> c. 1600, "to select by lot and put to death every tenth man," ***from Latin decimatus.***”

Etymonline